# How to edit "page plug-in" code of facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, graph

I am a beginner to facebook graph api.I have a facebook page,https://www.facebook.com/ILMISM .In my website I want to place button,so that whenever people click on that button they could like my page.I googled on it and watched many videos on youtube,though didn't get it properly.Finally I copied and pasted some code provided by facebook in my source file.That code is

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/ILMISM" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="false"></div>
```

and I got output as shown in the following image.

[image]

But I don't want my output like this.So I want to edit this code as,

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/ILMISM" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="false"><img src="like us on facebook.png"  /></div>
```

Then it is showing output as follows

[image]

Now whenever user clicks on on this button they could like my page.I am unable find an answer to how to achieve this?

Comment: You can not use your own arbitrary image as a Like button, you can only choose different sizes for the Like button layout that Facebook offers: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#link

Comment: if i want to make a button and whenever user clicks on that button he can like my page,how would i achieve that?

Comment: That is not possible, you have to use the Like button that Facebook provides to like Facebook pages.

Answer (score 1):

Like [CBroe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350762/how-to-edit-page-plug-in-code-of-facebook-graph-api#comment46892470_29350762) states, you cannot create some button which will make a user like your page instantly. you will have to use the [page plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin).

There is one other solution, however, which only applies to web apps that implement a server side OAuth 2 login flow: Once your users are logged into your webapp, your server can publish a `og.likes` OpenGraph action on the user's behalf. You can implement this functionality anywhere in your app and make it look any way you want, but you should be aware that Facebook enforce their [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) and branding policies.

For more information, please see the [`og.likes` docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes), especially the [`branding guidelines`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes#requirements) about this. Be aware that using any OpenGraph action in your app requires that you submit it for review, as documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions)